# Duplicate a Random Number function from JS to C#

Tags: c#

I got this function in JS

```
var number = Math.random() + "";
var r = number * 10000000000000;
```

I need the 100% same function in C# as I'm new to C# I'm having hard time getting a function for this in C# for people who are familer or not with JS Math.random() will generate a number between 0 to 1 similar to this (0.7740926130209118, 0.6105941028799862) and then I would like to multiply by 10000000000000 and we get something like "2647182801738.3813 <---This is what I need.

I thought about creating a 13 digits random number and another 4 digit random number and just add it like 13 digit + . + 4 digits. This of course is not ideal but I'm having issues with it as well.

```
Random random = new Random(); int randomNumber = random.Next(1000000000000, 9999999999999);
```

will give me errors about `int`, What I understand is I should use `long`? but when I change `int` to `long` it still looks like random function itself is INT? Well I'm already confused of what I have found online, So It will be great if you can help with this one and explain how  does it work.

Comment: Whatever approach you take, make sure you keep the same instance of Random rather than creating a new Random object every time as that won't generate a series of very random numbers for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haven't tested but sounds like you need:

```
 Random random = new Random();

 long r = (long)(random.NextDouble() * 10000000000000);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want an exact port, go for something like:

```
var number = (new Random()).NextDouble() * 10000000000000;
```

Answer (score 0):

C# also has a `var` :)

```
using System;

public class Test
{
        public static void Main()
        {
           Random randObj = new Random();
           var number = randObj.NextDouble( ) * 10000000000000;
           Console.WriteLine( number ); 
        }
}
```

...

```
input: no
output:
6426401076105.61
```